# Canvas Transparency creating perminant after-image

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I am trying to achieve a tracing effect where the lines have a faded trail. The way I am trying to do it is simply by drawing the solid background once, and then on further frames draw a transparent background before drawing the new lines, so that you can still see a little of the image before it.

The issue is that I do want the lines to fade out completely after some time, but they seem to leave a permanent after image, even after drawing over them repeatedly.

I've tried setting different globalCompositeOperation(s) and it seemed like I was barking up the wrong tree there.

This code is called once

```
//initiate trace bg
traceBuffer.getContext("2d").fillStyle = "rgba(0, 30, 50, 1)";
traceBuffer.getContext("2d").fillRect(0, 0, traceBuffer.width, traceBuffer.height);
```

then inside the setInterval function it calls

```
//draw transparent background
ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 30, 50, 0.04)";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);

//set drawing settings
ctx.strokeStyle = "#AAAAAA";
ctx.lineWidth = 4;

for (let i = 0; i < tracer.layer2.length; i++){
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(newX, newY);
    ctx.lineTo(oldX, oldY);
    ctx.stroke();
}
```

Here's an example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hPKNW.png

On the left is what I am currently getting, and on the right is the edit of what I actually want to happen.

Comment: You have to blank it out (use requestAnimationFrame for better synchronisation)

Comment: @QuentinUK can you explain a little more? If by "blank out," you mean clear the canvas, then that is what I am trying not to do. Instead of clearing it, I want to draw over the previous canvas using transparency to create a "ghost," of the image before it, the problem is the ghost is not going away no matter how many times I draw over it.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Basic_animations

Comment: Thanks, but again, not really what I am trying to do. I changed the system to use requestAnimationFrame as it seems more "proper," but it has no effect on my issue. I am basically trying to create a "double negative," where the new image is constantly drawn over the old. I want there to be _some_ persistence so that it fades away over time, but no matter how many times I re-draw over it using a semi-transparent BG, it seems to cap out at a minimum and just stay there.

Comment: You 'll have to keep a linked list of previous positions. Completely erase the line then redraw with varying opacities. (You can use b-splines for the line segments)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would do it. I would build a history of the particles moving on the track. The older the position the smaller the value of the alpha value for the fill. Also for a nicer effect I would reduce the size of the circle.

I hope this is what you need.

PS: I would have loved to have your curve. Since I don't have it I've drawn a different one.

```js
const hypotrochoid = document.getElementById("hypotrochoid");
const ctx = hypotrochoid.getContext("2d");
const cw = (hypotrochoid.width = 300);
const ch = (hypotrochoid.height = 300);
const cx = cw / 2,
      cy = ch / 2;

ctx.lineWidth = 1;
ctx.strokeStyle = "#d9d9d9";
// variables for the hypotrochoid
let a = 90;
let b = 15;
let h = 50;
// an array where to save the points used to draw the track
let track = [];
//add points to the track array. This will be used to draw the track for the particles
for (var t = 0; t < 2 * Math.PI; t += 0.01) {
  let o = {};
  o.x = cx + (a - b) * Math.cos(t) + h * Math.cos((a - b) / b * t);
  o.y = cy + (a - b) * Math.sin(t) - h * Math.sin((a - b) / b * t);
  track.push(o);
}


// a function to draw the track
function drawTrack(ry) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(ry[0].x, ry[0].y);
  for (let t = 1; t < ry.length; t++) {
    ctx.lineTo(ry[t].x, ry[t].y);
  }
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.stroke();
}


// a class of points that are moving on the track
class Point {
  constructor(pos) {
    this.pos = pos;
    this.r = 3;//the radius of the circle
    this.history = [];
    this.historyLength = 40;
  }

  update(newPos) {
    let old_pos = {};
    old_pos.x = this.pos.x;
    old_pos.y = this.pos.y;
    //save the old position in the history array
    this.history.push(old_pos);
    //if the length of the track is longer than the max length allowed remove the extra elements
    if (this.history.length > this.historyLength) {
      this.history.shift();
    }
    //gry the new position on the track
    this.pos = newPos;
  }

  draw() {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.history.length; i++) {
      //calculate the alpha value for every element on the history array
      let alp = i * 1 / this.history.length;
      // set the fill style
      ctx.fillStyle = `rgba(0,0,0,${alp})`;
      //draw an arc
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(
        this.history[i].x,
        this.history[i].y,
        this.r * alp,
        0,
        2 * Math.PI
      );
      ctx.fill();
    }
  }
}


// 2 points on the track
let p = new Point(track[0]);
let p1 = new Point(track[~~(track.length / 2)]);

let frames = 0;

let n, n1;

function Draw() {
  requestAnimationFrame(Draw);
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cw, ch);
  //indexes for the track position 
  n = frames % track.length;
  n1 = (~~(track.length / 2) + frames) % track.length;
  //draw the track
  drawTrack(track);
  // update and draw the first point
  p.update(track[n]);
  p.draw();
  // update and draw the second point 
  p1.update(track[n1]);
  p1.draw();
  //increase the frames counter
  frames++;
}

Draw();
```

```css
canvas{border:1px solid}
```

```html
<canvas id="hypotrochoid"></canvas>
```

Comment: Still not quite what I was trying to do, but if I decided to get it perfectly working I think this would be the way I would have to do it. I was hoping that my method of physically leaving the after image would make it more "universal," but it seems that HTML5 canvas doesn't add alphas together in the same way something like photoshop does, where 50% transparency added on top of itself will eventually erase what is under it. I could also imagine manually doing it by subtracting directly from the canvas image data.